# One data versus 2 datas in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there any big difference:

```
data Point = IntPoint Int Int
           | FloatPoint Float Float
```

over

```
data IntPoint = IntPoint Int Int
data FloatPoint = FloatPoint Float Float
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with it.

```
data Point = IntPoint Int Int
           | FloatPoint Float Float
```

Here the same type `Point` has two data constructors `IntPoint` and `FloatPoint`. For example, you can write a single function that takes a value of type `Point` and do something with it depending if it is an `IntPoint` or a `FloatPoint`. Here is an example function which checks if the line joining origin and the point forms 45 degree with x-axis.

```
isDiagonal :: Point -> Bool
isDiagonal (IntPoint i j) = i == j
isDiagonal (FloatPoint i j) = i == j
```

On the other hand,

```
data IntPoint = IntPoint Int Int
data FloatPoint = FloatPoint Float Float
```

Here `IntPoint` and `FloatPoint` are separate types with `IntPoint` and `FloatPoint` as data constructors respectively. Now you have to write separate functions having different names for each type.

```
isDiagonalInt :: IntPoint -> Bool
isDiagonalInt (IntPoint i j) = i == j

isDiagonalFloat :: FloatPoint -> Bool
isDiagonalFloat (FloatPoint i j) = i == j
```

There are ways to write a polymorphic function for the above case using typeclasses but thats another story.